# Feed ocamlyacc parser from explicit token list?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

Is it possible to feed an OCamlYacc-generated parser an explicit token list for analysis?

I'd like to use OCamlLex to explicitly generate a token list which I then analyze using a Yacc-generated parser later. However, the standard use case generates a parser that calls a lexer implicitly for the next token. Here tokens are computed during the yacc analysis rather than before. Conceptually a parser should only work on tokens but a Yacc-generated parser provides an interface that relies on a lexer which in my case I don't need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a list of tokens, you can just go the ugly way and ignore the lexing buffer altogether. After all, the parse-from-lexbuf function that your parser expects is a non-pure function :

```
let my_tokens = ref [ (* WHATEVER *) ]
let token lexbuf = 
  match !my_tokens with 
    | []     -> EOF 
    | h :: t -> my_tokens := t ; h 

let ast = Parser.parse token (Lexbuf.from_string "")
```

On the other hand, it looks from your comments that you actually have a function of type `Lexing.lexbuf -> token list` that you're trying to fit into the `Lexing.lexbuf -> token` signature of your parser. If that is the case, you can easily use a queue to write a converter between the two types:

```
let deflate token = 
  let q = Queue.create () in
  fun lexbuf -> 
    if not (Queue.is_empty q) then Queue.pop q else   
      match token lexbuf with 
        | [   ] -> EOF 
        | [tok] -> tok
        | hd::t -> List.iter (fun tok -> Queue.add tok q) t ; hd 

let ast = Parser.parse (deflate my_lexer) lexbuf
```

Comment: A yacc-generated parser provides semantic actions access to position information hidden in the `lexbuf` state. I am therefore not sure that `deflate` will work but it gives me an idea.

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned by Jeffrey, [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) specifically offers, as part of its runtime library, a module to the parsers with any kind of token stream (it just asks for a `unit -> token` function): [MenhirLib.Convert](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/convert.mli.html).

(You could even use this code without using Menhir, with ocamlyacc instead. In practice the conversion is not terribly complicated so you could even re-implement it yourself.)

Comment: That's very useful. I never used Menhir but the manual looks very convincing (I had overlooked the `Convert` module, though) and its author is well respected in the OCaml community.

Answer (score 1):

The OCamlYacc interface does look pretty complicated; it seems to require a `Lexing.lexbuf`.  Maybe you could consider using `Lexing.from_string` to feed a fixed string rather than a fixed sequence of tokens.  You could also look at [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/).  I haven't used it, but it gets excellent reviews here whenever anybody mentions OCaml parser generators.  It might have a more flexible lexing interface.

Comment: Menhir looks like a good alternative to OCamlYacc for many reasons. However, it also seems pretty closely tied to the lexer. `Lexing.from_string` is not an alternative because the essential problem is that some lexer actions generated two tokens rather than one because I can only recognize the token following an arbitrary string and end up with a string token and the one following it. Hence I had planned on building up a list of tokens first. Maybe I have to introduce weird hybrid tokens to work around the limitation.